# How to fill in missing value of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na, missing-data

I have multiple `columns` that has `missing values`. I want to use the `mean` of the same day across all years while `filling` the `missing` data for each `column`. for example, `DF` is my fake data where I see `missing` values for the `two columns (A & X)`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1985-01-01"), to = as.Date("1987-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 A = sample(1:10,1095, replace = T), X = sample(5:15,1095, replace = T)) %>% 
                replace_with_na(replace = list(A = 2, X = 5))
```

To `fill` in `Column A`, i use the following code

```
Fill_DF_A <- DF %>% 
          mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
          group_by(Year, Day) %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(is.na(A), mean(A, na.rm=TRUE), A))
```

I have many `columns` in my `data.frame` and I would like to generalize this for all the `columns` to fill in the missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
      group_by(Year, Day)  %>%
     mutate(across(A:X, na.aggregate))
```

---

Or if we prefer to use conditional statements

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Day)  %>%
  mutate(across(A:X, ~ case_when(is.na(.) 
                 ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))))
```